# writing the equations in mathematical form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem in writing the equation in mathematical form. I have these equations

$$
(1+ax)(1+bx) = 1 + (a+b)x + abx^2,\\
(1+ax)(1+bx)(1+cx) = 1 + (a+b+c)x + (ab+ac+bc)x^2 + abcx^2,\\
(1+ax)(1+bx)(1+cx)(1+dx) = 1 + (a+b+c+d)x + (ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd)x^2 + (abc + abd + acd + bcd) x^3+ abcdx^4.\\
$$

As it is seen if I generalize it, it becomes a sum of the values as a constant for $x$, the choose of 2 of them from the whole set and then times these two number with together and sum them up as a constant for $x^2$ etc. Now I want to write them in mathematical form, but I do not have any idea how can I do it. I appreciate in advance for any help.

Thank you
EM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_ix)=1&+\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\Bigr)+\Bigl(\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} a_ia_j\Bigr) x^2+\dots \\ & + \sum_{1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n}\mskip -24mu a_{i_1}\dotsm\, a_{i_k} \cdot x^k +\dots +\Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\Bigr)x^n\end{align*}

is a possibility. You also can write in this formula:
$$\sum_{1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n}\mskip -24mu a_{i_1}\dotsm\, a_{i_k} \cdot x^k=\sum_{1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n}\Bigl(\prod_{l=1}^k a_{i_l}\Bigr)\cdot x^k.$$

Comment: Thank you Bernard. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Let the coefficients be the indexed set
$A \equiv \{ a_1 \ldots a_n \}$ and use the usual notation for any finite set $S$ that the number of elements is written as $|S|$.

Then you can write your relation as

$$
\prod_{i = 1}^n (1+a_i x) = \prod_{\alpha \in A} (1+\alpha x)= \sum_{S \subseteq A} x^{|S|}\prod_{\beta\in S}\beta
$$

Note that hhis also uses the usual convention that an empty product has value $1$.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer. I appreciate